# Multiplication Of Digits in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

What's the Easiest way to read implementation of calculating the Multiplication of Digits in C#?

*For Exp: The Number: `12587 => Result : 1*2*5*8*7=560`*

for Sum of Digit we have this Lambda Expression:

`number.ToString().Sum(x=>x-'0');`

I Want same Expression For Multiply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent of `Sum` for multiplication, but you could use `Aggregate`:

```
number => number.ToString().Aggregate(1, (acc, digit) => acc * (digit - '0'))
```

I'd be tempted to separate out the "convert digits to integers" part from the aggregation though:

```
number => number.ToString()
    .Select(c => c - '0')
    .Aggregate(1, (acc, next) => acc * next)
```